# I've ran into an issue with filling

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, subdivision-surface

[image]I was modelling my old camera when i saw that after filling faces mesh gets weird shading and vertices stick to edges.[image: Weird]

[image: fill]

Comment: Hello, I would say it's inverted normals (SHIFT + N in edit mode) or double vertices

Comment: If Gorgious answer doesn't fix the problem, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, It worked